# Rails file location and access

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My root is `site/home/ubuntu/workspace/`

1. Is it possible to access file (from browser by HTTP request) located inside `workspace/` without configuring routes and controllers?
2. Does the question on 1) depend on file extension?

Comment: access from where? You can access to every location from your rails server.

Comment: Please add (in an edit to your question NOT a comment) some more detail about what you want to do, eg what you mean by "access" and the location of the file.

Comment: Access the root path, then go back (..)

`"#{Rails.root}/../"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without configuring routes and controllers, client can only access files in the `public/` directory (it doesn't matter what the extension is). 
 
 Bare in mind this: when your Rails app is run by webserver, its webroot will be the public directory, consequently to access `public/file.ext` you request should be `webroot/file.ext`

Answer (score 0):

I have this structure:

```
# /home/username/Workspace/rails_project/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
require "#{Rails.root}/../test.rb
```

And

```
# /home/username/Workspace/test.rb
# Some ruby code
```

As you can see, `test.rb`file is outside RubyOnRails Project.

For security reason, you can not access a file outside project rails from URL without defining a route. What you can do, is point a route to controller that, based on file name provided at url, require a file outside rails project.

```
# /home/username/Workspace/rails_project/config/routes.rb
get '/get_file/:file_name', to: 'files#show'

# /home/username/Workspace/rails_project/app/controllers/files_controller.rb
class FilesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        document = params[:file_name]
        send_data "#{Rails.root}/../#{document}, filename: document
    end
end
```

> For more info, see:
>   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data

Comment: Still, not what I was looking for. You can see my own answer to get the idea of what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can access path to your file like this:

```
File.expand_path("somestuff.rb", "~/workspace")
```

for me this code produces path as follows:

```
"/home/foodie/workspace/somestuff.rb"
```